# Save file xls in dynamic directory

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create a macro that saves the xls file in a specific directory called Months in this directory there are 12 other directories with the name of the months.
I wrote a Macro where the file is saved in the directory months, but I need that the file is saved in a specific directory based from the value of the month in the cell of my sheet. 
Below my code:

```
Sub Macro1()
```

'
' Macro1 Macro
' Salva con nome giorno e data
'
' Scelta rapida da tastiera: CTRL+p
'

```
NomeFile = Range("B2").Value 'Cella da cui prendere il nome file
NomeCartella = Range("D2").Value 'Cella da cui prendere il nome del mese
NomeFoglio = Range("A2").Value
If NomeFile = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(NomeFile, 4) <> ".xls" Then NomeFile = NomeFile & ".xls"

Cartella = "C:\Users\Michele\Documents\la piazzetta\Mesi\" 'percorso completo su cui salvare
CartellaMese = NomeCartella
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Cartella \ CartellaMese & NomeFile, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=False



End Sub
```

Comment: I think you are missing a few & and " signs here:
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Cartella & "\" & CartellaMese & NomeFile, FileFormat:=xlNormal,

Comment: Hi Michele. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Gabor worked but I needed to add some other things here the Whole code

```
Sub Macro1()
NomeFile = Range("B2").Value 'Cella da cui prendere il nome file
NomeCartella = Range("D2").Value **& "\"** 'Cella da cui prendere il nome del mese
NomeFoglio = Range("A2").Value
If NomeFile = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(NomeFile, 4) <> ".xls" Then NomeFile = NomeFile & ".xls"

Cartella = "C:\Users\Michele\Documents\la piazzetta\Mesi" 'percorso completo su cui salvare
CartellaMese = NomeCartella
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Cartella & "\" & CartellaMese & NomeFile, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This should look like this:

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Cartella **& "\" &** CartellaMese & NomeFile, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=False